# kubectl asking for username (k8s cluster created via kops)

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kops

I created a kubernetes cluster using `kops` and deployed it in AWS (not EKS manual cluster using `kops`).

Then I export in my local machine the configuration like
`kops export kubecfg --state ${KOPS_STATE_STORE} --name ${NAME}`

Then running any kubectl command asks for a username, even `kubectl` version

```
 kubectl version
Please enter Username:
```

PS: If I `ssh` into bastion host then `ssh` into k8s master node, kubectl works fine and its configuration is referring to local user created.

My local config created from export command into `~/.kube/config` looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: fakedata=
    server: https://api-test-intern-doesntmatter.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com
  name: test-internet.k8s.local
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: test-internet.k8s.local
    user: test-internet.k8s.local
  name: test-internet.k8s.local
current-context: test-internet.k8s.local
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: test-internet.k8s.local
  user: {}
```

And with the config above I cannot do any `kubectl` command.
Where can I find the username and password for `kubectl`?
I have set authentication as RBAC for the cluster and no limitations.

I read all article here https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/ and still do not understand what is the default username password why am I asked for such credentials I haven't created any role or user.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this temporarily with not the safest solution, but is working
When creating secret with kops named admin, can use that to generate user field in exported kops config by adding also

`--admin` in the export command

Answer (score 0):

If you are using test clusters then just use

```
kops update cluster ${NAME} --yes --state ${KOPS_STATE_STORE} --admin
```

Read more at

https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/releases/1.19-NOTES.md#changes-to-kubernetes-config-export

Answer (score 0):

you can fix this by entering below command

```
kops export kubecfg --admin
```